# Why tensorflow eats up so many RAM even when training on TPU & how to free the memory allocated after training

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory

I'm using `tf-1.15` and use `tf.TPUEstimator` ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/tpu/TPUEstimator)) to for model training. The model is running perfectly except that it uses around 3GB RAM. This is toleratable alone, but I'm looping to train more than 10 such models and the RAM is never freed, so it adds up consumes more than 30GB RAM... I've tried

```
del estimator
gc.collect()
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

yet it seems not working.

Any suggestions on how could I reduce the tensorflow memory usage or at least free them once one training is finished? Great thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm solution found. It seems that TF would hold the resources until the process terminates (correct me if I was wrong). So how I solve the problem is to wrap the session/estimator and its running inside another Process:

```
def core_run(args, kwargs):
    """ running the TF """
    ...
    return results

from multiprocessing import Pool
# preparing args and kwargs
with Pool(1) as p:
   results = p.apply(core, args, kwargs)
```

In this way, TF would have to release the resources since the process it's in reach the end